# Rust: Method "poll" not found in `impl std::future::Future`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn async programming, but this very basic example doesn't work:

```
use std::future::Future;

fn main() {
    let t = async {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    };
    t.poll();
}
```

Everything I've read from the specs says this should work, but cargo complains that method "poll" can't be found in "impl std::future::Future". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your code? Usually you won't use `.poll` directly when writing asynchronous applications, instead you would use `await` or methods from [`FutureExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html).

Comment: I'm mostly just learning how the system works. I can't use await in a non-async context, so I'm trying to figure out how to call an async method in a non-async context.

Answer (score 8):

[`poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) has this signature:

```rust
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output>;
```

There are two problems with calling this in the way you do:

1. `poll` is not implement on a future `Fut`, but on `Pin<&mut Fut>`, so you need to get a pinned reference first. [`pin_mut!`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/macro.pin_mut.html) is often useful, and if the future implements [`Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html), you can use [`Pin::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.new) as well.
2. The bigger problem however is that `poll` takes a `&mut Context<'_>` argument. The context is created by the asynchronous runtime and passed in to the `poll` function of the outermost future. This means that you can't just poll a future like that, you need to be in an asynchronous runtime to do it.

Instead, you can use a crate like [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/) or [`async-std`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1/async_std/) to run a future in a synchronous context:

```rust
// tokio
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
let runtime = Runtime::new().unwrap();
let result = runtime.block_on(async {
  // ...
});

// async-std
let result = async_std::task::block_on(async {
  // ...
})
```

Or even better, you can use [`#[tokio::main]`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/attr.main.html) or [`#[async_std::main]`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1/async_std/attr.main.html) to convert your `main` function into an asynchronous function:

```rust
// tokio
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  // ...
}

// async-std
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
  // ...
}
```