# No method named `poll_next` found for struct `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver<&str>` in the current scope

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to compile some code similar to this:

```rust
use tokio::stream::Stream;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (sender, mut receiver) = mpsc::channel(2);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        sender.send("Hello");
    });

    println!("{:?}", receiver.poll_next())
}
```

But the compiler tells me:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll_next` found for struct `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver<&str>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
12 |     println!("{:?}", receiver.poll_next())
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver<&str>`

warning: unused import: `tokio::stream::Stream`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use tokio::stream::Stream;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

But my IDE (IDEA with rust plugin) tells me the method exists in `[...]/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-0.3.5/src/sync/mpsc/bounded.rs`:

```rust
cfg_stream! {
    impl<T> crate::stream::Stream for Receiver<T> {
        type Item = T;

        fn poll_next(mut self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<T>> {
            self.chan.recv(cx)
        }
    }
}
```

And so does `tokio`'s doc: https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.5/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.poll_next

Both the macro and the doc say this is behind the `stream` crate feature, but I am using `tokio = { version="0.3.5", features = ["full"] }`.

So why is this method not available to me?

Edit:

My IDE also insists on making me import `tokio::stream::Stream` while the compiler tells me it is unused.

Comment: Maybe you need to `use futures::stream::Stream` to opt into the methods implemented for the trait.

Comment: Same error with `use futures::stream::Stream;`

Comment: @user4815162342 Edited:  I've removed the loop from this example code so we can focus on the compilation error.

Comment: OK it's the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61347849/1685538, the method is defined on `std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>` and not just `Self`.
Using `pin_mut!` gives me the next error with the missing context.
Using `try_recv` actually does what I want.
Closing.